# Como fazer para validar um valor sem sair da página?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, aplicação-web

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com a parte do desconto, então queria que o usuário digitasse o desconto e que após ele terminar que validasse se tem ou não e aparecesse a porcentagem do desconto.

```
$cupom = $this->input->post('cupom_desconto');
$desconto = $this->desconto_model->buscarDesconto($cupom, $atividade_codigo);
```

Essa é a maneira como estou fazendo, mas desse jeito está enviando o request para outra página e gostaria que fosse feito na mesma página, exemplo da Netshoes e outras que colocamos o código e se for válido aparece na mesma página o valor do desconto, caso tenha, senão não altera nada.

Comment: o que você ja fez ? poste um exemplo do seu progresso.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues A maneira que eu tô fazendo é passando pra outra página, o usuário digita o código e na outra página eu faço a verificação.

`$cupom = $this->input->post('cupom_desconto');
  $desconto = $this->desconto_model->buscarDesconto($cupom, $atividade_codigo);`

Comment: edite sua pergunta e coloca essas informações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma sugestão é fazer por jQuery.

Fiz um exemplo pra ti:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4aneafx/)

Basicamente:

```
$("#valorPorcentagem").change(function(e, j){
    var valorDigitado = this.value;
    var valorProduto = 300.00;

    if (valorDigitado == "") {
        alert("Sem desconto!")   
    } else {
        alert("O produto terá um desconto de: " + valorDigitado + "%. Valor final do produto: R$" + ( ((100-valorDigitado)/100) * valorProduto));  
    }
});
```